# How do I save the instance state of a LinearLayout in Android?

Tags: android, save, android-linearlayout

in my app I dynamically set the visibility of a linearlayout. The problem is that on rotation of the device, the state of the linear layout (visible or not) is not saved.

Now I would like to save the state with the help of saving the instance state of the layout.
Can someone help me with the according methods? What values do I have to provide?

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // ??
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // ???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would save the instance state by saving either a boolean or integer value in the bundle:

```
private static final VISIBILITY_KEY = "anthing you want";

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    boolean isVisible = . . .;
    outState.putBoolean(VISIBILITY_KEY, isVisible);
}
```

You would read it back in as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    boolean isVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(VISIBILITY_KEY);
    // do something with isVisible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the visibility as an integer in the Bundle.

```
private final static String VIEW_1_VISIBILITY = "view_1_visibility";
private View mView1;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(VIEW_1_VISIBILITY, mView1.getVisibility());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mView1.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(VIEW_1_VISIBILITY, View.VISIBLE));
    }
}
```

Comment: What can I do to use this in a sherlockfragment? for the ònRestoreInstanceState`I get `The method onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) of type ABC must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: There is an example in the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html. It seems that you can do that in `onActivityCreated()`